# coordinates of ordered basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $n>2$ is an integer.

Consider the ordered basis $\{B_0,B_1,...,B_n\}$ of the space of polynomials over the complex numbers of degree $n$ or less, call it $P_n$ where $B_k=t^k$. Consider the following family of linear transformations from $P_n$ to $P_n$ given by:

$$Tp(x)=(ax^2+bx-c)p''(x)+(dx+e)p'(x) $$

where $a, b, c, d$ and $e$ are fixed complex numbers. Give the coordinates of $T(B_k)$ in this ordered basis for each basis element of $B_k$.

What is $p(x)$? My thinking is once I know $p(x)$, then I can compute $p'(x)$ and $p''(x)$ and multiply it out, collect like terms and find the coordinates of the ordered basis then, correct?

Comment: I've added LaTeX to your post. I assumed you meant $(ax^2+bx-c)p''(x)$ rather than $(ax^2+bx_c)p''(x)$.

Comment: It looks to me like the problem you're working on just mixed up $t$ and $x$.  Although maybe it's not technically wrong, it's confusing.  Just replace all the $x$ in the question with $t$ and see if that helps.

Comment: yeah that's right, thanks.  I am new to this so the formatting is a little hard

Comment: So if I replace all of the x's with t's, then what would my p(t) be? Because I want to find p"(x) and p'(x) in order to find hte ordered basis correct?

Comment: $p(t)$ is the vector on which $T$ is operating, so in this case it's $B_k$.

Comment: So Since B_k=t^k, then p'(t)=t^k and p"(t)=t^k also and I substitute those into the equation to find the coordinates of the ordered basis?

Comment: The derivative of $t^k$ is $k\cdot t^{k-1}$ if $k\neq 0$

Comment: Now I think I got it, thank you